# Unable to Delete Product Entity in Spring Boot JPA with Hibernate-No error shown in console or in Logs

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, many-to-many

I am working on an eCommerce application using Spring Boot with JPA and Hibernate for database operations. I have entities Product, Category, Brand, and Company with bidirectional relationships. When I try to delete a Product entity, it does not get deleted from the database, and no error is thrown. Here are my entity classes and service method for deleting a Product:

Brand Entity

```
package com.ecommerceapp.entitys;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonBackReference;
import jakarta.persistence.*;
import jakarta.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import jakarta.validation.constraints.Size;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

import java.util.List;

@Entity
@Table(name = "brand_table")
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Brand {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long b_id;

    @NotNull(message = "Brand name cannot be null")
    @Size(min = 3, message = "Brand name should have at least 3 characters")
    private String b_name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "p_brand", cascade = CascadeType.ALL,fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JsonBackReference
    private List<Product> products;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Brand{" +
                "b_id=" + b_id +
                ", b_name='" + b_name + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

Category Entity

```
package com.ecommerceapp.entitys;


import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonBackReference;
import jakarta.persistence.*;
import jakarta.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import jakarta.validation.constraints.Size;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

import java.util.List;

@Entity
@Table(name = "category_table")
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor

public class Category {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long cat_id;
    @NotNull(message = "Category cannot be null")
    @Size(min = 3, message = "Category name should have at least 3 characters")
    private String cat_name;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "p_category", cascade = CascadeType.ALL,fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JsonBackReference
    private List<Product> products;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Category{" +
                "cat_id=" + cat_id +
                ", cat_name='" + cat_name + '\'' +
                '}';
    }

}
```

Company Entity

```
package com.ecommerceapp.entitys;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonBackReference;
import jakarta.persistence.*;
import jakarta.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import jakarta.validation.constraints.Size;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

import java.util.List;

@Entity
@Table(name = "company_table")
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Company {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long comp_id;
    @NotNull(message = "Company cannot be null")
    @Size(min = 3, message = "Company name should have at least 3 characters")
    private String comp_name;

    @NotNull(message = "Company location cannot be null")
    @Size(min = 3, message = "Company location should have at least 3 characters")
    private String comp_location;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "p_company", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JsonBackReference
    private List<Product> products;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Company{" +
                "comp_id=" + comp_id +
                ", comp_name='" + comp_name + '\'' +
                ", comp_location='" + comp_location + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

Product Entity

```
package com.ecommerceapp.entitys;

import jakarta.persistence.*;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

@Entity
@Table(name = "product_table")
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Product {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long p_id;
    private String p_name;
    private Long p_price;
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "p_brand", referencedColumnName = "b_id")
    private Brand p_brand;
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "p_category", referencedColumnName = "cat_id")
    private Category p_category;
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "p_company", referencedColumnName = "comp_id")
    private Company p_company;

}
```

Now Service class for product service

```
package com.ecommerceapp.services;


import com.ecommerceapp.DTOs.ProductDTO;
import com.ecommerceapp.entitys.Product;
import com.ecommerceapp.exceptionHandlers.EntityNotFoundException;
import com.ecommerceapp.repos.ProductRepo;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;


@Service
public class ProductService {
    public static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ProductService.class);
    @Autowired
    private ProductRepo productRepo;

    @Autowired
    private CategoryService categoryService;
    @Autowired
    private BrandService brandService;
    @Autowired
    private CompService compService;

    public Product addOrSaveProduct(Product product) {
        return productRepo.save(product);
    }

    public List<Product> getAllProducts() {
        return productRepo.findAll();
    }

    public Product getProductById(Long id) throws EntityNotFoundException {
        Optional<Product> myProduct = productRepo.findById(id);
        if(myProduct.isPresent()){
            return myProduct.get();
        }else{
            throw new EntityNotFoundException("Product not found");
        }
    }

    public Product setProductFields(Product product, ProductDTO productDTO) throws EntityNotFoundException {
        product.setP_name(productDTO.getP_name());
        product.setP_price(productDTO.getP_price());
        product.setP_category(categoryService.getCategoryById(productDTO.getP_category()));
        product.setP_brand(brandService.getBrandById(productDTO.getP_brand()));
        product.setP_company(compService.getCompanyById(productDTO.getP_company()));
        return product;
    }
    public Product toProduct(ProductDTO productDTO) throws EntityNotFoundException {
        Product newProduct = new Product();
        return setProductFields(newProduct, productDTO);
    }

    public Product updateProduct(Product existingProduct, ProductDTO productDTO) throws EntityNotFoundException {
        return setProductFields(existingProduct, productDTO);
    }


    public void deleteProduct(Long productId) throws EntityNotFoundException {
        Product product = productRepo.findById(productId)
                .orElseThrow(() -> new EntityNotFoundException("Product with ID " + productId + " not found"));
        productRepo.delete(product);
    }

}
```

product repository interface

```
package com.ecommerceapp.repos;

import com.ecommerceapp.entitys.Product;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public interface ProductRepo extends JpaRepository<Product, Long> {

}
```

I have used a product DTO class to add and update the product.

```
package com.ecommerceapp.DTOs;

import jakarta.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import jakarta.validation.constraints.Size;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class ProductDTO {

    private Long p_id;
    @NotNull(message = "Product name cannot be null")
    @Size(min = 3, message = "Product name should have at least 3 characters")
    private String p_name;
    @NotNull(message = "Product price cannot be null")
    private Long p_price;
    @NotNull(message = "Brand cannot be null")
    private Long p_brand;
    @NotNull(message = "Category cannot be null")
    private Long p_category;
    @NotNull(message = "Company cannot be null")
    private Long p_company;

}
```

Product Controller class

```
package com.ecommerceapp.controllers;


import com.ecommerceapp.DTOs.ProductDTO;
import com.ecommerceapp.entitys.Product;
import com.ecommerceapp.exceptionHandlers.EntityNotFoundException;
import com.ecommerceapp.services.ProductService;
import jakarta.validation.Valid;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import java.util.List;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/products")
public class ProductController {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ProductController.class);

    @Autowired
    private ProductService productService;

    @PostMapping("/addProduct")
    public ResponseEntity<Product> addProduct(@RequestBody @Valid ProductDTO productDTO) throws EntityNotFoundException {
        Product product = productService.toProduct(productDTO);
        logger.info(product.toString());
        productService.addOrSaveProduct(product);
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.CREATED).body(product);
    }


    @GetMapping("/getAllProducts")
    public ResponseEntity<List<Product>> getAllProducts() {
        List<Product> allProducts = productService.getAllProducts();
        logger.info(allProducts.toString());
        return ResponseEntity.ok(allProducts);
    }

    @GetMapping("/getProduct/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<Product> getProductById(@PathVariable Long id) throws EntityNotFoundException {
        Product myProduct = productService.getProductById(id);
        logger.info(myProduct.toString());
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK).body(myProduct);
    }

    @PutMapping("/updateProduct/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<?> updateProduct(@PathVariable Long id, @RequestBody @Valid ProductDTO productDTO) throws EntityNotFoundException {
        Product exProduct = productService.getProductById(id);
        Product updatedProduct = productService.updateProduct(exProduct, productDTO);
        productService.addOrSaveProduct(updatedProduct);
        return ResponseEntity.ok("Product details updated successfully");
    }

    @DeleteMapping("/deleteProduct/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<?> deleteProduct(@PathVariable Long id) throws EntityNotFoundException {
        productService.deleteProduct(id);
        logger.info("deleted");
        return ResponseEntity.ok("Product deleted successfully");
    }
}
```

I have verified that the Product entity is fetched correctly, and the delete method is called without any exceptions. The message product deleted successfully has been shown in postman while testing, However, the product is not deleted from the database. How can I troubleshoot this issue and ensure that the Product entity is deleted properly? Any suggestions or insights would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

I want the product to be removed from database

Comment: You are not using the ```@Transactional``` annotation on any of your service methods that modify the database. Give that a try first.